# Create Destination Conditioning For Custom Links

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, hyperlink, share

**Hello**. I hope I can be clear enough. So, I have an app where I embed my website, when the url, **http://action_share** is executed, the app understands it and shares the app. However, when the link is clicked on the web, it takes one to the actual url which doesn't exist. Is there a way to define a destination page for that url if there's no command executed (like the app does), or rather, also create a share command even on the web.
I hope you understand my question.

Edit: I want the link, **http://action_share** to refer users to a page in my website

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, I added an edit, I want the link, http://action_share to refer users to a page in my website.